# Session Mocking-Rhino Mocks

Tags: rhino-mocks

I want to mock the following in my action controller using RhinoMocks

```
Session["myId"] = someGuid.ToString();
```

How Do I do that?

Thank you

Comment: what exactly you want to mock?

Comment: I want to mock Session["myId"]

Comment: What is underlying type of the Session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download MVC Contrib from Codeplex http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/ or using NUget. Add the references to your .net project and follow the example below:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyController()
{
    //Mocks your controller with the session
    TestControllerBuilder builder = new TestControllerBuilder();
    HomeController controller = new HomeController();
    builder.InitializeController(controller);

    ViewResult result = controller.MyController() as ViewResult;

    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```